# how to read from .csv file and store in database in asp.net using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, csv

i am uploading a .csv file with data .. now i have to read this data from this .csv file and store it in database ...
i have done this with excel but i can't use excel in this project so i have a code for excel like this :

```
private bool writetoven()
{

    OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);

    try
    {
        OleDbCommand ocmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", excelConnection);
        excelConnection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader odr = ocmd.ExecuteReader();
        string vcode = "";
        string pswd = "";
        string vname = "";



        while (odr.Read())
        {
            vcode = valid(odr, 0);
            pswd = valid(odr, 1);
            vname = valid(odr, 2);

            insertdataintosql(vcode,pswd,vname);
        }
        excelConnection.Close();
        return true;
    }
    catch (DataException)
    {
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {

        excelConnection.Close();
        lblmsg4.Text = "Data Inserted Sucessfully";

    }


}
```

no what to do for .csv files .. i have never used .csv file before so want some help on this

Comment: check this out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30705/C-CSV-Import-Export

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to use a library like FileHelpers 
http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/

No need to code all the details and the plumbing yourself. Also it is quite fast and flexible.

Comment: why not? You will be done in 5 minutes and it will be much better than most of what you come up yourself with.